# How to compare the value of two/multi column array and add into listbox without dupllication in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, arrays

Hi I've small project to do and now I'm stuck in middle.

The program is to read the sequential text file and load it into a array/array of structure.

The data information is like this (sample):

```
ID | Name    | Type
1  | Cat     | Animal
2  | Dog     | Animal
3  | Parrot  | Bird
4  | Tuna    | Fish
5  | Tiger   | Animal
6  | Sparrow | Bird
```

Sample data in the DATA.txt file looks like this:

```
1;Cat;Animal
2;Dog;Animal
3;Parrot;Bird
4;Tuna;Fish
5;Sparrow;Bird
6;Tiger;Animal
```

This is Just as sample data, my original data is more than this.

I've open the DATA.txt file using FileStreamReader:

```
Dim FileStreamReader As StreamReader = New StreamREader(DATA.txt)
```

Read all the elements in the list and pass through `ReadArrayString`.
Split the string using:

```
DataString.Split(New Char() {";"c})
```

Pass through

```
ReadArrayString(0)
ReadArrayString(1)
ReadArrayString(2)
```

Where index 0 is the ID, index 1 is the name, and index 2 is the Type

Then I load the types in the dropdown combobox menu from the array with out duplication. Like this:

```
If TypeComboBox.FindString(ReadArrayString(2)) < 0 Then
  TypeComboBox.Items.Add(ReadArrayString(2))
End If
```

Now When you click TypeComboBox it will show drop down menu with following list only.

```
Animal
Bird
Fish
```

After this, when Animal type is selected/clicked from combobox dropdown menu then it should only add the Id and Name of Animal type in the ListBox.

Pseudocode may looks like this:

```
If Animal is selected/clicked from TypeComboBox then
  Add Cat into listbox
  Add Dog into listbox
  Add Tiger into listbox
Else If Bird is selected then
  Add Parrot into listbox
  Add Sparrow into listbox
Else If Fish is selected then
  Add Tuna in to listbox
End If
```

I've only figure out load items from only one column/array into combobox with out duplication.
But can't figure out to compare the value of one column/array with another column/array and load it into listbox. I don't want to hardcode or write matching value inside the code. What I want is use the Array.

Any help will be great.

Sorry if my explanation is poor. I hope above  pseudocode may give you some understanding of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misunderstanding your question, something like this should work, for what you are trying to do.

```
For Each row as String() In TwoDArray
    If row(2) = TypeComboBox.Text Then
        listbox.Items.Add(row(1))
    End If
Next
```